# How to fix my RockPaperScissors game written in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a RockPaperScissors game for my Java class but I'm having trouble with my code. When it runs, sometimes it outputs the wrong thing and sometimes it is correct.

For example when the user enters P the computer is either supposed to answer with Tie, My Point, or Your Point, and then under it will say what each of us played. But often it will say some thing like "Your Point!" "R beats R".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RockPaperScissors
{       
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   int tie = 0;
   int win = 0;
   int loss = 0;

   String playerChoice;
   System.out.println(RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice());

   while (true) 
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("(R)ock, (P)aper, (S)cissors, or quit: ");

        playerChoice = input.nextLine();


        if (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) break;
        else            
               //switch statement

            if (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(
                RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice()))
            {
                System.out.println("Tie!");
                tie++;
            }

            else if ((playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && 
                        RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice().equals("S")) ||
                    (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("P") && 
                        RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice().equals("R")) ||
                    (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && 
                        RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice().equals("P")))
            {
                System.out.println("Your Point!");
                System.out.println(playerChoice + " beats " 
                    + RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice());
                win++;

            }

            else if ((playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && 
                        RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice().equals("P")) ||
                    (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("P") && 
                        RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice().equals("S")) ||
                    (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && 
                        RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice().equals("")))
            {
                System.out.println("My Point!");
                System.out.println(RockPaperScissors.getComputerChoice() 
                    + " beats " + playerChoice);
                loss++;

            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input!");

            }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You won " + win + " times.");
    System.out.println("You lost " + loss + " times.");
    System.out.println("We tied " + tie + " times.");
}


public static String getComputerChoice ()
{

    int compChoiceInt;
    String compChoice;
    compChoiceInt = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    switch (compChoiceInt)
    {
        case 0:
            compChoice = "R";
            break;
        case 1:
            compChoice = "P";
            break;
        case 2:
            compChoice = "S";
            break;
        default:
            compChoice = "Invalid Input";
            System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
            break;
    }

    return compChoice;

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `getComputerChoice` over and over again? Declare a variable, assign the result of a single call to the function to it, and then use it in your switch (which you seem to have decided to change to a series of `if..else` statements instead). The function call should be at the same point in the loop where you're getting the player's input.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `getComputerChoice()` many times in your code that decides if the user wins, loses, or ties. That can result in several *different* possible outcomes to each round because each one of those method calls results in a new choice being randomly generated. Instead of calling that method several times, declare a variable and call it just once, before you compare it to the player's choice.